# How to cache all backend in the Rails?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to temporarily cache all requests in the Rails backend?

Sometimes it's helpful to make frontend stuff without waiting for the backend on the page to reload.

Comment: To enable [caching in development](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#caching-in-development) there's `bin/rails dev:cache`. It creates or removes `tmp/caching-dev.txt` which is checked for in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: What you might actually want here instead is a mocked backend. This lets you prototype stuff in the frontend before the backend implementation exists and lets you run tests without worrying about resetting the state in backend. For example [Mirage.js](https://miragejs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very ambiguous. If you don't want to wait on the backend for development then you can cache your requests on the front-end using local storage or other client-specific APIs.

On the other hand, if you need backend caching it won't really serve your purpose because the client will still need to make the API call.

Lastly, if you need to mock your APIs then there are multiple such tools available. One that I like is https://designer.mocky.io/